# Defining anonymous functions in a loop including the looping variable?

Tags: javascript, html

I know that this code doesn't work and I also know why.
However, I do not know how to fix it:

JavaScript:

```
var $ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); };
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()
{
    for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        $('a' + i).addEventListener('click', function()
        {
            console.log(i);
        });
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="a1">1</a>
<a href="#" id="a2">2</a>
<a href="#" id="a3">3</a>
```

I want it to print the number of the link you clicked, not just "4".
I will prefer to avoid using the attributes of the node (id or content), but rather fix the loop.

Comment: [Coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/) has the very handy `do` keyword just for this kind of situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap the loop block in its own anonymous function:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()
{
        for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            (function(i) {
                $('a' + i).addEventListener('click', function() {
                    console.log(i);
                })
            })(i);
        }
}
```

This creates a new instance of `i` that's local to the inner function on each invocation/iteration. Without this local copy, each function passed to `addEventListener` (on each iteration) closes over a reference to the *same variable*, whose value is equal to `4` by the time any of those callbacks execute.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the inner function is creating a closure over `i`.  This means, essentially, that the function isn't just remembering the value of `i` when you set the handler, but rather the variable `i` itself; it's keeping a live reference to `i`.

You have to **break** the closure by passing `i` to a function, since that will cause a **copy** of `i` to be made.

A common way to do this is with an anonymous function that gets immediately executed.

```
        for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            $('a' + i).addEventListener('click', (function(localI)
            {
                return function() { console.log(localI); };
            })(i);
        }
```

Since you're already using jQuery, I'll mention that jQuery provides a [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function that can be used to simplify code like this:

```
        for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            $('a' + i).data("i", i).click(function()
            {
                console.log($(this).data("i"));
            });
        }
```

Here, instead of breaking the closure by passing `i` to an anonymous function, you're breaking it by passing `i` into jQuery's `data` function.

Comment: I wasn't using jQuery just the basic $ = document.getElementById ;)

Comment: I was wondering why you were doing `$('a' + i).addEventListener` instead of `$('a' + i).click` -- oh well, some superfluous jQuery info :)

Answer (score 0):

The closure captures a reference to the variable, not a copy, which is why they all result in the last value of the 'i'.

If you want to capture a copy then you will need to wrap it in yet another function.